# Executar uma função após o carregamento total da página

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho uma página que carrega diversas tabelas, depois as organiza em abas.

Teria como executar uma função ao finalizar todo o carregamento da página  ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pode usar o evento `$(window).on("load"...`:

```
$(window).on("load", function(){
   // página totalmente carregada (DOM, imagens etc.)
});
```

É bem diferente do `$(document).ready(function()...`, que apenas dispara quando o DOM foi carregado, mas pode haver elementos assíncronos (imagens, scripts) ainda sendo carregados.

> Vale lembrar que o método `.load()` para o evento `load` do JavaScript tornou-se obsoleto no jQuery
>   1.8 e removido do 3.0. ([Veja documentação](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/)). Use `.load()` apenas como *shorthand* de Ajax no jQuery ([veja documentação](http://api.jquery.com/load/)).

Comment: Qual a diferença desse seu para esse: `$(window).load(function() {})`

Comment: Opa! Na parte amarela da resposta tá explicadinho.

Comment: Nossa, tapa na minha cara ! Cego demais ! rs

Comment: @RBZ já que você pediu, toma https://i.stack.imgur.com/tY276.jpg

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo não sei se tomar o tapa é pior, ou ser o Robin ! hahahah

Comment: @Sam como fazer esse load com javascript puro?

Comment: @Tiago Seria: `window.onload = function(){ // código aqui }`

Comment: @Sam já tetei isso tambem, veja se consegue me ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/429850/erro-em-ao-passar-valor-para-o-input-cannot-set-property-value-of-null

Comment: Tenta [isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/376197/8063)... apaga o que tem dentro do `if` e no lugar coloca `inputExibeNome();`.. e remova o onload do body.

Answer (score 2):

```
window.onload = function () { alert("Está carregado!") }
```

- Por padrão, ele é disparado quando a página inteira é carregada, incluindo seu conteúdo (imagens, css, scripts, etc.)
- Em alguns navegadores, ele agora assume o papel de document.onload e é acionado quando o DOM também está pronto.

> window.onload parece ser o mais amplamente suportado. De fato, alguns dos navegadores mais modernos, em certo sentido, substituíram `document.onload` por `window.onload`. Os problemas de suporte ao navegador são provavelmente a razão pela qual muitas pessoas estão começando a usar bibliotecas como o jQuery para lidar com a verificação de que o documento está pronto da seguinte forma:

```
$(document).ready(function() { /* code here */ }); $(function() { /* code here */ });
```

Fonte [**brothers site**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033398/how-to-execute-a-function-when-page-has-fully-loaded/1033448#1033448)

Answer (score 1):

Há duas maneiras de se carregar uma função após o carregamento da página, pode ser pela tag `<body>` ou por `jquery`

Veja por exemplo:

```
<body onLoad="nome_função();">
```

Com esse método, após o carregamento total de tudo que há dentro da tag `<body>`, ele irá rodar a função.

O segundo método seria esse:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(window).on("load", function(){
   //seu script aqui
})

</script>
```

Então você especifica no **src** do primeiro script que citei, onde está o seu arquivo jquery (ou usar o link direto para o arquivo).

Comment: `$(window).load(function(){})` não funcionou...

Comment: Como o dvd disse ali em cima, ele virou obsoleto e na versão mais recente do jquery foi substituída. Então para substituir veio o: $(window).on("load", function(){}. Esqueci dessa observação que foi bem lembrada por ele.

Answer (score 1):

no seu arquivo JavaScript põe:

```
document.onload(funcaoPaginaCarregada())
function funcaoPaginaCarregada() {
// coloca o que a função vai fazer após a página ser carregada
}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Veja que as respostas são 2018 de lá para cá as coisa mudaram um pouco. Os [event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#other_event_listener_mechanisms) devem desincentivados enquanto [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#using_addeventlistener) devem ser adotados. Considere [edit] e reformular sua resposta.