# Evento keypress e filtrar dados após inserir valor em qualquer input do form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-datatables, jquery-ui

Olá, estou tentando fazer um filtro na minha SPA com um formulário para inserção de dados.

Tenho um formulário com 3 inputs text, e minha intenção é no campo de vendedor,digitar o nome do vendedor (tenho um autocomplete nesse input) e apertar o Enter no teclado, e após isso ele me trazer os dados na minha tabela que está abaixo do meu formulário, mas a minha ideia é realizar o filtro independente dos campos digitados, caso eu digitar o nome do cliente no campo de cliente, retorna os dados após o Enter, se eu digitar Endereço ou N° de Contrato realizar o filtro, como um Submit, seria praticamente um submit com o botão Enter do teclado.

Já fiz um filtro de uma maneira que está funcional, mas minha ideia seria usar uma função e colocar no formulário, com o evento 'onkeypress' recebendo a minha função, o modo que estou fazendo agora está diretamente na tag do form, que foi como eu fiz funcionar e está fazendo o filtro, meu objetivo é digitar em qualquer campo clicar no Enter e filtrar, independente do campo digitado.

Vou deixar abaixo como estou fazendo agora para filtrar(note na linha da tag form a forma que achei pra fazer o filtro no evento do botão):

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Filtros")" method="POST" id="formFiltros" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { submitFormFiltro(); }">
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="control-group">
                            <div class="row-fluid">
                                <div class="span3 ">
                                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.NumeroRegistroCliente, "Nº Contrato")
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        @Html.TextBoxPermissionFor(x => x.NumeroRegistroCliente)
                                    </div>
                                </div>                                    
                                <div class="span3" style="margin-top: 25px;">
                                    @if (Model.IsRVS)
                                    {
                                        <label for="ApenasRVSRASComRetificacao">
                                            @Html.CheckBoxPermissionFor(x => x.ApenasRVSRASComRetificacao)
                                            Mostrar apenas RVS com retificação.
                                        </label>
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        <label for="ApenasRVSRASComRetificacao">
                                            @Html.CheckBoxPermissionFor(x => x.ApenasRVSRASComRetificacao)
                                            Mostrar apenas RAS com retificação.
                                        </label>
                                    }
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            @if (Model.IsRVS)
                            {
                                <div class="row-fluid">
                                    <div class="span6">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.IdGrupoEmpresa, "Vendedor")
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            @Html.TextBox("GrupoEmpresaAutoComplete", "", new { placeholder = "Digite um vendedor(cnpj ou nome)..." })
                                            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.IdGrupoEmpresa)
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="span6">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.IdCliente, "Adquirente")
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            @Html.TextBox("ClienteAutoComplete", "", new { placeholder = "Digite um adquirente..." })
                                            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.IdCliente)
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <div class="row-fluid">
                                    <div class="span6">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.IdFornecedor, "Vendedor")
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            @Html.TextBox("FornecedorAutoComplete", "", new { placeholder = "Digite um vendedor..." })
                                            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.IdFornecedor)
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="span6">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.IdGrupoEmpresa, "Adquirente")
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            @Html.TextBox("GrupoEmpresaAutoComplete", "", new { placeholder = "Digite um adquirente(nome ou cnpj)..." })
                                            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.IdGrupoEmpresa)
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
<div class="form-actions">
                    <div style="float: right">
                        <button id="btnFiltro" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submitFormFiltro();">
                            <i class="icon-filter icon-white"></i>Filtrar
                        </button>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="limparFiltro();">
                            Limpar
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Minha ideia seria criar uma função lá no arquivo JavaScript,e chamar ela no form, vou deixar o trecho de código que tentei fazer e não retornou o filtro:

```
    function submitInputsFilter() {
    $('#formFiltros').on(("keypress", function (e) {
        var value = $(this).val()  || !value;

        if (e.keyCode == 13 ) {
            $('#formFiltros').submit();
        }
    }));
}
```

Tentei chamar esse método submitInputsFilter(); onde está a tag form, mas ele não retornou nada.

Da maneira que está agora, realizando o filtro, está chamando como referência o método que está no botão filtrar, mas eu gostaria de fazer um método que é executado da mesma forma que o botão, somente com o click do Enter.

Qualquer ajuda é valida para eu melhorar meus conhecimentos, obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use o *event handler* fora da função quando a página estiver completamente carregada. Para isso coloquei `document.onreadystatechange` com a condição `complete`.

No `value` coloquei `.trim()` para que não dispare o `.submit()` caso seja digitado apenas espaços. No seletor coloque `input` após o `#formFiltros` para capturar o evento de qualquer input dentro do formulário. E além da condição `e.keyCode == 13` no `if`, coloque `&& value` para que só dispare o `.submit()` se a variável `value` tiver dados.

Ficará assim:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function(){
   if(document.readyState == "complete"){
      $('#formFiltros input').on("keypress", function(e){
         var value = $(this).val().trim();
         if(e.keyCode == 13 && value){
            $('#formFiltros').submit();
         }
      });
   }
}
```