# JavaScript DOM e Canvas

Tags: javascript, dom, canvas

Tenho um problema que eu não consegui resolver por mais que eu tentasse, é o seguinte:
No meu projeto eu criei uma função para criar uma cor média com base nas cores da imagem, mas as vezes me retorna o seguinte erro e minha aplicação para:

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The source width is 0.

[Erro no console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRAil.png)

Aqui está a função:

```
function averageColor(imageElement) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),

        context = canvas.getContext && canvas.getContext('2d'), imgData, width, height, length,
        rgb = { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0 },
        count = 0
    height = canvas.height =
        imageElement.naturalHeight ||
        imageElement.offsetHeight ||
        imageElement.height
    width = canvas.width =
        imageElement.naturalWidth ||
        imageElement.offsetWidth ||
        imageElement.width
    context.drawImage(imageElement, 0, 0)
    imgData = context.getImageData(1, 1, width, height) // Aqui é onde ocorre o erro
    length = imgData.data.length

    for (let i = 0; i < length; i += 4) {
        rgb.r += imgData.data[i]
        rgb.g += imgData.data[i + 1]
        rgb.b += imgData.data[i + 2]
        count++
    }

    // Creating an average color
    rgb.r = Math.floor(rgb.r / count)
    rgb.g = Math.floor(rgb.g / count)
    rgb.b = Math.floor(rgb.b / count)

    return rgb
}
```

O erro pode ser melhor visto no projeto disponível online na seguinte URL: https://vanortton.github.io/Bento/index.html

O repositório: https://github.com/Vanortton/Bento

Comment: Boas-vindas Vanortton. Perguntas não podem depender de links externos para contextualizar, por isso é importante ler e compreender o [mcve] ao formular suas perguntas. Sobre o erro, provavelmente a imagem em imageElement não está disponível, por isso width=0. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045). *Agradecemos a compreensão*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se quer calcular a cor média duma imagem uma solução é redimensionar sua imagem para o tamanho de 1 pixel e ler esse pixel.

Para criação de buffers e desenho em memória prefira utilizar [`OffscreenCanvas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas) ao invés de criar canvas on fly como fez em:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
```

Isso porque operações gráficas podem vir a impactar negativamente a performance do sistema e quando cria um canvas com [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) esse elemento é criado no [thread principal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Main_thread) da aplicação o que pode ocasionar slowdowns em algumas aplicações mais robustas do ponto de vista gráfico. Use essa abordagem apena com [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossary/Polyfill) caso o navegador não suporte contextos de renderização fora de tela, veja em [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/offscreencanvas).
Quando possível prefira utilizar estruturas especializadas em [contextos de renderização fora de tela](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvasRenderingContext2D) ao invés da improvisação.

Especificamente sobre o erro que vem recebendo:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The source width is 0.
```

O [erro que está recebendo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData#exceptions) indica que a imagem cujo que está tentando processar no momento em que tenta aplicar [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.getImageData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) está dimensionada com zero pixels de comprimento.
Com os dados pa pergunta não é possível distinguir se a causa do problema:

- Uso de fonte de imagens mal formadas.
- Uso de fonte de imagens não carregadas ou parcialmente carregas durante o processamento.
- Erros de origens desconhecida.

A não ser o problema com uso de fonte de imagens não carregadas ou parcialmente carregas durante o processamento, o uso de fonte de imagens mal formadas ou os erros de origens desconhecida não podem se tratados por essa resposta.

No caso de uso de fonte de imagens ainda não completamente carregadas faça com que sua função `averageColor()` seja aplicada apenas quando a fonte de imagens esteja disponível.

Uma forma bastante direta seria [adiar a execução de todo seu script até que todas as imagens estejam carregadas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/295654/137387) usando o evento [`Window: load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event).

```js
window.addEventListener('load', (e) => {


  function averageColor(imgElem) {
    const canvas = new OffscreenCanvas(1, 1); //var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')

    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(imgElem, 0, 0, 1, 1);
    const imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1);
    return {
      r: imgData.data[0],
      g: imgData.data[1],
      b: imgData.data[2]
    };
  }


  const imagem = document.getElementById("imagem");
  console.log(averageColor(imagem));

});
```

```html
<img id="imagem" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
/>
```

Outra possibilidade seria tornar sua função `averageColor()` em uma [função assíncrona](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) e aguarda o carregamento total da fonte de imagem a ser processada até que uma [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) seja realizada ou rejeitada:

```js
function waitForImage(imgElem) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    if (imgElem.complete) {
      return res();
    }
    imgElem.onload = () => res();
    imgElem.onerror = () => rej(imgElem);
  });
}

async function averageColor(imgElem) {
  await waitForImage(imgElem);
  const canvas = new OffscreenCanvas(1, 1);  //var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')

  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(imgElem, 0, 0, 1, 1);
  const imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1);
  return {
    r: imgData.data[0],
    g: imgData.data[1],
    b: imgData.data[2]
  };
}

const imagem = document.getElementById("imagem");
averageColor(imagem).then(c => {
  console.log(c);
})
```

```html
<img id="imagem" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
/>
```

<sup>A função `awaitForImage()` foi extraída [dessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69486344/11379709) e cujo o autor é [ya_dimon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2519073/ya-dimon).</sup>

Comment: Obrigado man. Consegui criar uma solução a partir da sua resposta.